# ESP8266 TIMEOUT: 428

Tags: esp8266, arduino-mega, esp8266webserver

this is the code I used:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "WiFiEsp.h"
// Emulate Serial1 on pins 6/7 if not present
#ifndef HAVE_HWSERIAL1
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
SoftwareSerial Serial1(18, 19); // RX, TX
#endif

char ssid[] = "Vodafone-A61356555";            // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "xxxx";        // your network password
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;     // the Wifi radio's status
int reqCount = 0;                // number of requests received

WiFiEspServer server(80);

int MPU = 0x69;
int MPU1 = 0x69;
int16_t AcX, AcY, AcZ, Tmp, GyX, GyY, GyZ;
int16_t AcX1, AcY1, AcZ1, Tmp1, GyX1, GyY1, GyZ1;
int gyro_state = 2;
int gyro_state_1 = 3;
int RED_LED = 8;
int GREEN_LED = 9;

void setup(){
  pinMode(gyro_state, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(gyro_state_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RED_LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GREEN_LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(gyro_state, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(gyro_state_1, HIGH);
  Wire.begin(); 
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // initialize serial for ESP module
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  // initialize ESP module
  WiFi.init(&Serial1);

  // check for the presence of the shield
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
  }

  // attempt to connect to WiFi network
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  }

  Serial.println("You're connected to the network");
  printWifiStatus();
  
  // start the web server on port 80
  server.begin();
}


void loop(){
  // listen for incoming clients
  WiFiEspClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("New client");
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        Serial.write(c);
        // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
        // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
        // so you can send a reply
        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
          Serial.println("Sending response");
          
          // send a standard http response header
          // use \r\n instead of many println statements to speedup data send
          client.print(
            "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
            "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
            "Connection: close\r\n"  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
            "\r\n");
          client.print("<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n");
          client.print("<html>\r\n");
          client.print("<br>\r\n");
          client.print("Accelerometro X: ");
          client.print(AcX);
          client.print("<br>\r\n");
          client.print("</html>\r\n");
          break;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        }
        else if (c != '\r') {
          // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(10);

    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected");
  }
  digitalWrite(gyro_state, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(gyro_state_1, LOW);

  do{
    Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
    Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
    Wire.endTransmission(false);
    Wire.requestFrom(MPU, 14, true);       // request a total of 14 registers
    AcX = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)
    AcY = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
    AcZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
    Tmp = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();  // 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) & 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
    GyX = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
    GyY = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
    GyZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();  // 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) & 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)

    Tmp = Tmp / 340 + 36.53;

    digitalWrite(gyro_state_1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(gyro_state, LOW);
    delay(1000);

  }while(digitalRead(gyro_state)== HIGH);

  do{
    Wire.beginTransmission(MPU1);
    Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
    Wire.endTransmission(false);
    Wire.requestFrom(MPU1, 14, true);       // request a total of 14 registers
    AcX1 = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)
    AcY1 = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
    AcZ1 = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
    Tmp1 = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();  // 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) & 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
    GyX1 = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
    GyY1 = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
    GyZ1 = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();  // 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) & 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)

    Tmp1 = Tmp1 / 340 + 36.53;

    digitalWrite(gyro_state, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(gyro_state_1, LOW);
    delay(1000);


  }while(digitalRead(gyro_state_1) == HIGH);
}


void printWifiStatus()
{
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);
  
  // print where to go in the browser
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("To see this page in action, open a browser to http://");
  Serial.println(ip);
  Serial.println();
}
```

This is what I see in the serial monitor with a baud of 115200:

```
[WiFiEsp] Initializing ESP module
[WiFiEsp] Initilization successful - 1.5.4
Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: Vodafone-A61356555
[WiFiEsp] Connected to Vodafone-A61356555
You're connected to the network
SSID: Vodafone-A61356555
IP Address: 192.168.1.30

To see this page in action, open a browser to http://192.168.1.30

[WiFiEsp] Server started on port 80
[WiFiEsp] New client 0
New client
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host[WiFiEsp] TIMEOUT: 428
Client disconnected
[WiFiEsp] New client 0
New client
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host[WiFiEsp] TIMEOUT: 428
Client disconnected
```

Comment: please add a `this is my question` section to your post

Comment: it is a known problem of the WiFiEsp library which is not maintained anymore. if you can update the AT firmware,, you can use my WiFiEspAT library

Comment: I tried to change the library but it tells me to change WiFiEspServer to WiFiServer and for WiFiEspClient it tells me Compilation error: 'WiFiEspClient' was not declared in this scope

Comment: of course. it is a different library